# cyclic run depends

Tags: ros, catkin, jenkins, package.xml, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

in a `package.xml` file it is possible to declare a package only as `run_depend` without declaring it as a `build_depend`. So you can have two packages depending on each other without having problems building them.

When you try to auto generate documentation for these packages, using the buildfarm, the script first scans the dependencies and constructs a directed graph in order to know which package should be build first. Building fails because you can not have a circular dependency when you are building packages.

The question is whether, a `run_depend` on a packet implies that you are also `build_depend` on that packet? This would seem logical. Otherwise, I can not see a reason why you can not have cyclic run depends between packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118781/cyclic-run-depends/) by [czalidis](https://answers.ros.org/users/10926/czalidis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`<run_depend>` does *not* imply `<build_depend>`

But your dependency graph *may not* have cycles, i.e. a package may not directly or indirectly depend on itself.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bluenote](https://answers.ros.org/users/37779/bluenote/) on 2018-11-22**:
Literally "may not" means that it can have cycles. Is that what you mean or do you mean "must not"?